# Jotai + React: unexpected re-rendering, and unexpected stale state value

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management, react-lifecycle, react-lifecycle-hooks

I'm making a game that, like most games, has various scenarios that can be triggered from anywhere else in the game.

I opted to use Jotai as I found it very easy to use as a global state management tool. Jotai atoms behave a bit like `setState` and `useContext` combined.

### The Lead-up

I'm storing the player's energy in an atom. When the energy reaches `0`, a `useEffect` in the `<EnergyLevel />` component triggers a change in a "global event state" atom. *That* change is picked up the parent `<Game />` component, which conditionally renders the `<EndGame />` component if the global event state value is an "end game" value.

The user can click "Start Over", which resets the global event state value and a global "active screen" value, which triggers the main menu to be rendered. At this point, the global event state has been *explicitly* set to `NONE`.

When the user clicks on "Load Last Game"--which sets a "loading state" atom--the parent `<Game />` component re-renders and its `useEffect` conditionally calls a derived, write-only atom that gets the last saved game from a database and sets all the other atoms to those values. It also resets any global state tracking atoms to the defaults for a freshly loaded game.

### The Bug

Technically, everything actually renders as expected up until this point, but for one *additional* component: the `<EndGame />` component is rendered *again*, after `<Game />` is finished loading.

Looking into this further (and with many console.logs), I found that another render is triggered *after* the expected final render (after useEffect) of `<Game />`, and during that unexpected phase, the global event atom value, which was explicitly set to `NONE`, is somehow reset to the old event value.

### The Question

What is causing the additional render cycle as I reference in the second paragraph of the **The Bug** section above? And why is the `eventTriggeredOfType` atom value changing during this unexpected render?

### The Code

Reproducible code with this odd behavior [is sandboxed here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/jotai-ts-incorrect-component-triggering-8prxi?file=/public/index.html) Just follow the instructions once loaded.

Here are some snippets to demonstrate the intended logic:

```js
// here's the function that decreases playerEnergy, which is triggered by a button
// Game.tsx
const [playerEnergy, setPlayerEnergy] = useAtom(playerEnergyAtom);
const decreaseEnergy = () => {
   setPlayerEnergy(playerEnergy <= 0 ? 0 : playerEnergy - 10);
};


// then I watch playerEnergy and set the an event state to NO_ENERGY if it is 0
// EnergyLevel.tsx
const [, setEventTriggeredOfType] = useAtom(eventTriggeredOfTypeAtom);
useEffect(() => {
  if (playerEnergy <= 0) setEventTriggeredOfType(EventType.NO_ENERGY);
}, [playerEnergy, setEventTriggeredOfType]);


// here is the EndGame component that is only rendered when
// shouldTriggerEndGame returns true
// Game.tsx
const [shouldTriggerEndGame] = useAtom(shouldTriggerEndGameAction);
if (shouldTriggerEndGame) return <EndGame />;


// here is the shouldTriggerEndGame atom that checks the event state
// gameActions.ts (this file holds all the atoms)
export const shouldTriggerEndGameAction = atom((get) => {
  // this is what returns stale atom value SOMETIMES
  const eventTriggeredOfType = get(eventTriggeredOfTypeAtom); 
  return [
    eventTriggeredOfType === EventType.NO_ENERGY
  ].some((triggerState: boolean): boolean => triggerState === true);
});


// here is the "Start Over" button handler that resets the EventType above:
// EndGame.tsx
const goBackToMainMenu = () => {
    setEventTriggeredOfType(EventType.NONE);
    // triggers a return to the main screen (always works)
    setActiveScreen(Screen.NONE);
};


// these are triggered by UI buttons from the user
// gameActions.ts
export const startNewGameAction = atom(null, (_get, set) => {
  set(resetDefaultGameState, null);
  set(isLoadingGameOfTypeAtom, LoadType.NEW);
});

export const loadLastGameAction = atom(null, (_get, set) => {
  set(resetDefaultGameState, null);
  set(isLoadingGameOfTypeAtom, LoadType.SAVED);
});


// isLoadingGameOfType is being watched from within <Game />
// Game.tsx
const loadSavedGameRef = useRef(loadSavedGame);
const createNewGameRef = useRef(createNewGame);
useEffect(() => {
  if (isLoadingGameOfType === LoadType.SAVED) loadSavedGameRef.current();
  if (isLoadingGameOfType === LoadType.NEW) createNewGameRef.current();
}, [isLoadingGameOfType]);


// these are triggered by <Game />'s useEffects when the appropriate
// eventTriggeredOfType values are true
// gameActions.ts
export const loadSavedGameAction = atom(null, async (get, set) => {
  const playerData = get(playerDataAtom);
  set(playerEnergyAtom, playerData.lastGameState.playerEnergy);
});

export const createNewGameAction = atom(null, (_get, set) => {
  set(playerEnergyAtom, 100);
});
```

Comment: Hi there,
Did you open this issue at Jotai on github?

Comment: I haven't, but I did avoid the problem by changing the flow of my functions calls. I haven't posted an answer here because my solution doesn't explain why this was an issue in the first place.

When I find an extra moment, I'll post on the Jotai github. Thanks Horacio!